# How Does WhatsApp overcome the GCM Push notifications delay?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, whatsapp

I am trying to use GCM service, Every thing is OK except of the long delay that GCM push notification or deliver payload... some times it take to my App 5 minutes receive notification or payload.
I need Immediate delivering...
I know about the roles of GCM, that wait until the other device got online,  but in my case I hold two devices and they are online, but I got Delayed notifications!

How does WhatsApp(as example of app that uses GCM) overcome this problem.. and send Immediately?

[ i.e (message of the type: typing, online - last seen)  cannot be delayed...]

---

the GCM Delayed Push is known problem : [this issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/connecting-to-networks-and-devices/fslYqYrULto%5B1-25-false%5D)
my question is: How other app that use GCM overcome this issue

Comment: [Reading the permissions when installing Whatsapp, I don't think they uses GCM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en). I think they are running a background service that is connected to their server, probably via a socket.

Comment: They do. They use the old version -  C2DM I saw there sharedprefs.

Comment: No i dont think so. Whatsapp is built using jabber server, which implements XMPP communication protocol.

Comment: Think it's [eJabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im) (alike).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When sending your notification you could set the [priority-parameter](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) to "high".

From the docs:

> By default, messages are sent with normal priority. **Normal priority optimizes the client app's battery consumption**, and should be used unless immediate delivery is required. For messages with normal priority, the app may receive the message with unspecified delay.
>
> When a message is sent with **high priority, it is sent immediately**, and the app can wake a sleeping device and open a network connection to your server.

I know this answer comes late, nevertheless if you are still facing this issue (or anyone else) please tell me if it helps.

Comment: I am now using the high priority when pushing the notification from the server. But notification is still delayed or can't receive when the phone is in sleep mode. Could you please give me suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

**The big players**

Lets focus on WhatsApp from a scale point of view. Their scale is global and one of the largest in terms of the market share. For players like these it becomes necessary to provide a consistent and smooth user experience no matter what the circumstances are. This means that the "small fish developers" like us are left with pre-defined rules by the big fish companies. Sometimes, it is the implementation that is challenging enough that a lot of the small time developers have to do with *whatever* is available.

I would like to take WhatsApp's Push Notification as an example to illustrate the above.

First of all, we must stop associating Push notification with Google's services(i.e, Google Play Services) exclusively. Would a device without Google Play services won't receive Push notifications? No, of course it can -- try focusing on the core mechanism of a push notification

**How do Push Notifications work - Sockets!**

Contrary to a protocol like HTTP which assumes a client-server architecture and is a uni-directional protocol(server can't initiate communication by itself), a plain socket enables communication bi-directionally.

You want to implement your own File transfer protocol over socket? You can!

You want to implement your own Chatting protocol over socket? You can!

You want to implement your own Push notifications protocol over socket? You can!

A socket is the canvas of communication over a network. You can pretty much do anything. Personally we have developed a custom request-response protocol in our organization.

**Multiple implementations**

Don't stick with default GCM/FCM notification messages protocol or implementation. You can deploy a mechanism to maintain a persistent socket connection with the device and can *listen* to whatever the server wants to **push**.

- WhatsApp uses both GCM/FCM as well as their proprietary XMPP server implementation for Push notifications
- WhatsApp(and several other Apps) rely upon GCM/FCM(as option 1 - the default) as it is present as a system App on lot of devices and therefore holds a special status where it is very less likely to be killed unlike a normal App.
- For devices that do not have play services, your custom socket connection is relied upon. It may be that FCM is preferred over socket when the former is available but those are upto you to manage.

From WhatsApp's latest build(2.19.203):

[image]

Notice that the relevant permission for FCM is present.

**Suspected socket implementation:** https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/how-is-whatsapp-able-to-receive-messages-when-not-in-use

**XMPP based Push Notifications**

From, https://www.quora.com/Does-WhatsApp-use-GCM-to-exchange-messages

> No, whatsapp doesn't use GCM[NOT entirely true]. It uses a modified version of XMPP
> called FunXMPP instead. It changes the XML keywords in message frames
> to save bandwidth as it's users aka mostly mobile network users,
> doesn't have a good internet connection. The replacements can be found
> here: [mgp25/Chat-API](http://mgp25/Chat-API) (I am not the author though)

They have even asked for whitelisting of any port(custom) in use by them.

So, WhatsApp does it. Facebook does it. Google does it. A lot of these companies do this. You can do it as well(to an extent) using Ejjaberd, Openfire or some other technology and having a proper client side implementation for the same.

**Chinese ROMs**

Some chinese ROMs have taken it even further and radically changed the way the memory and processes are managed in Android. As an example, in Oppo if the Application doesn't have Auto Start turned on, it will not let you do anything once your App is killed. No hopes of any experience whatsoever except hoping that the user will open the App again. In these cases, these OEMs have whitelisted WhatsApp, Facebook, Google and other players selectively. So, who suffers?

Us. Period.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Inspirational answer. Thank you sir