# Trying to exceed Push Notification Maximum Payload, writing own CCS XMPP connection?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I just have a quick question on the payload for Push notification.

I see that Whatsapp probably exceed the normal GCM or APNs server payload of 4kb and 2kb. As it can send Images over Push notification. I am just wondering if i want to have push notification that has a payload that exceed the max payload, does it mean writing a custom push notification service with CCS XMPP connection? that is show in the list below? Or would it be something totally different? I am just wondering. I am just trying to find a direction to learn here, to see how Whatsapp does it, that they can do such quick and large payload push notification.

Thanks for your time!

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

Comment: I don't think whatsapp using push notification technology behind it. They are using some other way where they have callback once message received/sent etc and chat server like ignite openfire etc.

Comment: Ah ok, cos i saw some people said they use C2DM, somebody else said they use jabber server that implements XMPP communication protocol on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743476/how-does-whatsapp-overcome-the-gcm-push-notifications-delay So i was wondering if there are any work around to have push notification, or instant notification that exceed that payload. I will check out Ignite realtime! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use AirBop in order to send images as Payload that gets displayed in the notification too.

Just follow this [tutorial](http://blog.andromo.com/2012/tutorial-using-airbop-to-send-images-in-the-message-payload/) and you would be all set to go.